# Update Table Column to Fill Missing Sequence No

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that have following data

```
CategoryID   Name   Sequence
10           One    1
10           Two    2
10           Three  4
20           One    1
20           Two    3
20           Three  4
30           One    1
30           Two    2
30           Three  3
```

Now I want to update the table for category id 10 and 20 so the sequence is corrected and final result is as folllows.

```
CategoryID   Name   Sequence
    10           One    1
    10           Two    2
    10           Three  3
    20           One    1
    20           Two    2
    20           Three  3
    30           One    1
    30           Two    2
    30           Three  3
```

I am trying to use common table expression but unable to do it. Any idea how to accomplish this task ?

I don't want to update each row one by one. I want to create a generic solution. So in case the recordset to update is large it is catered with same piece of code instead of copy pasting and changing values for every row.

Note:
The values in name column is imaginary for understanding purposes. It can be anything. For example Joe, USA etc

Comment: Is there any Table Column which shows row number or ID

Comment: Please view my another answer that may help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite hard to keep sequence numbers gapless. You would have insert/update/delete triggers to guarantee this.

However, it is not really needed, as you can always get gapless row numbers on-the-fly with the analytic function ROW_NUMBER:

```
select 
  categoryid, 
  name, 
  sequence, 
  row_number() over (partition by categoryid order by sequence)
from my table
order by categoryid, sequence;
```

Comment: Thats what I have used but using CTE I had some issues. I am trying temporary table now. If I succeed I'll post it.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE t
SET Sequence = RN
FROM
(
    SELECT Sequence, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID ORDER BY CategoryID) 
    AS RN FROM Table_1
) t
```

For Specific category id

```
UPDATE t
SET Sequence = RN
FROM
(
    SELECT Sequence, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID ORDER BY CategoryID) AS RN 
    FROM Table_1 
    WHERE CategoryID = 10
) t
```

Original Values

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: This is my table structure and values associated with it. 
Please check order by clause Use CategoryID for Order By

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand it correctly, but cant you do just:

```
Update table set sequence = 1 where Name = 'one';
Update table set sequence = 2 where Name = 'two';
Update table set sequence = 3 where Name = 'three';
```

Or am i missing something?

Comment: I want to create a generic solution. This will be hard coding and in case the update list is long it will take a lot of time.

Comment: @ItsZeus if you went up to 'nine' by hard coding, that would solve your problems wouldn't it?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I just posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with following piece of code to create generic solution. I have done unit testing. However corner cases may exists. It does the job for me though.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MY_TEMP_TABLE') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MY_TEMP_TABLE

CREATE table #MY_TEMP_TABLE(
CategoryID INT,
[Custom_Index] INT)

DECLARE @Index INT = 0 --
DECLARE @TotalParams INT = 0 --
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100)

INSERT INTO #MY_TEMP_TABLE
SELECT CategoryID, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Sequence]) AS [Custom_Index] 
FROM MY_ACTUAL_TABLE
WHERE CategoryID =  20

WHILE @Index < @TotalParams
BEGIN
    SET @Index = @Index + 1

    SELECT @Name = [Name] 
    FROM #MY_TEMP_TABLE
    WHERE #MY_TEMP_TABLE.[Custom_Index] = @Index

    UPDATE 
    MY_ACTUAL_TABLE
    SET [Sequence] = @Index
    WHERE CategoryID = 20 AND [Name] = @Name

END
```

Comment: I have used a variable for CategoryID so if in future I need to use the same script for another category, i don't need to search and replace it everywhere. Instead I just have to set the CategoryID variable and voila!